# dictionary attack sha512 hashes using hashlib with known salt for unix passwords

Tags: python, unix, sha512, cracking, hashlib

The question here is if i can use the hashlib module(sha512) to hash clear text from a file using the user's known salt from /etc/shadow to recreate the user's password hash?
Comparing the hash from my dictionary.txt with the users password hash from /etc/shadow (passwords.txt - `root:$6$1ZZlpDpQ$V1fZ.M2Y91Qzg7FCbj5rie/jHK6kOZB3rZVDXd1GldvyjFAYOl4Z2FZjc6uK9Q0lfvEjSiqRslGaddLVP2X3w0:17159:0:99999:7:::`) will tell me if the password in the list is indeed correct. Which does not seem to work.
What am i missing.
all help is appreciated

```
import hashlib
import sys

def checkpass(passwd):
try:
    semi_c = ':'
    d_sign = '$'
    pwdlist = passwd.split("$")
    salt = pwdlist[2]
    print 'Salt is : ' + salt
    cryptPas = passwd.split(d_sign, 3)[3]
    cryptPass = cryptPas.split(semi_c)[0]
    print cryptPass 
    dictFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')

    for word in dictFile.readlines():

            word = word.strip('\n')
            print 'Comparing to pass in list : ' + word + ' to ' + passwd + ' ---- '
            cryptWord = hashlib.sha512(salt + word).hexdigest()
            print 'Reproduced Hash : ' + cryptWord
            if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
                print '[+] Found Password : ' + word + '\n'
                return cryptWord
            else:
                print '[-] Password not found.\n'
                return cryptWord

except Exception, e:
    print e
return  

def main():

try:
    passfile = open('password.txt')
    passwd = passfile.readline()
    semi_c = ':'
    #print passwd
    if semi_c in passwd:
        user = passwd.split(semi_c)[0]
        print '[*] Cracking Password for : ' + user
        checkpass(passwd)
except Exception, e:
    print e
return    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This looks like a yes/no question, so i say: yes

Comment: When things don't work reduce the problem until it does succeed or you know why it fails. Then build on that. So first get the code to work with a known password and the password portion of the`etc/shadow` entry for it.

Comment: Current password hashing uses iteration such that ~100ms of CPU time is required per attempt. Just hashing a password even with a salt is not secure. Of course not all password schemes are designed to be secure and `etc/shadow` falls in the not-secure area.